# TypeError: The "digest" argument is required and must not be undefined

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I am getting subject error while registering a simple Mean Application through http://localhost:3000/auth/register, that I have simply created using `mean init` command. `pbkdf2` or `crypto` is generating the error and I have no idea where to look for it.

I have done lots of different things like cleared npm cache, reinstalled using npm etc. Please help me out. Following is some more information.

```
Mean --version: 0.12.15
npm --version: 5.0.3
node --version: v8.1.0
bower --version: 1.8.0
gulp --version: CLI and Local: 3.9.1
```

Code for `model.UserSchema.methods.hashPassword` (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\models\user.js)

```
/**
 * Hash password
 *
 * @param {String} password
 * @return {String}
 * @api public
 */
UserSchema.methods.hashPassword = function(password) {
  if (!password || !this.salt) return '';
  var salt = new Buffer(this.salt, 'base64');
  return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64).toString('base64');
};
```

Register page calls http://localhost:3000/api/register and it generates `500 Internal Server Error`.

Firefox is showing following response:

```
TypeError: The "digest" argument is required and must not be undefined
at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:635:11)
at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:628:10)
at model.UserSchema.methods.hashPassword (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\models\user.js:165:17)
at model.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\models\user.js:94:31)
at VirtualType.applySetters (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\virtualtype.js:94:25)
at model.Document.set (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:656:12)
at model._handleIndex (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:587:14)
at model.Document.set (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:547:24)
at model.Document (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:71:12)
at model.Model (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:46:12)
at new model (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3621:13)
at create (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\controllers\users.js:86:24)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at loadUser (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\controllers\users.js:202:24)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\connect-modrewrite\index.js:129:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio\lib\core_modules\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

Comment: Please post the code for model.UserSchema.methods.hashPassword (D:\Projects\Mean\CampaignBuilder\node_modules\meanio-users\server\models\user.js:165:17)

Comment: As I said I created the application using mean init, so it is default MEAN application. However, code is added for model.UserSchema.methods.hashPassword for ease of reference.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per the `crypto.pbkdf2Sync` method you are missing the final argument which is `digest`, thus the error being displayed.

[crypto.pbkdf2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest)

Also with further investigation you can see that the digest argument was required in Node v6.0.

The previous default seems to have been `'sha1'`.

Comment: Could you please guide what should I use for it? I mean should I use 'sha512' or 'md5' or whatever I want? Or do I need to check some other place or configuration of MEAN app before choosing anything? or just hard coded 'sha512' will be enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's working with 'sha512' (Login/Register both). So I assume decryption would also be working. I am new to MEAN, NodeJS and all this stuff and this was making me crazy as I didn't know anything.

Comment: Glad I could help, the documentation/ reading through the stack trace is always a great start for trying to debug. You'll get the hang of it in no time. Yeah if you can login then you're fine.

Comment: For the newbies like me, I did the following to make it working as suggested in this answer.

`return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512').toString('base64');`

Answer (score 7):

This could also be caused by the wrong version of node / running a version that has calls that are not supported in the version of node that you have  active

My Experience: My team has an application that requires Node 6.10.0. Sometimes I forget to switch to this version of node and run the latest code under 8.6.0 and I receive the same error.  As soon as I swap back to 6.10.0 the website will allow me to login.

(I can see that the accepted answer also mentions this, but I wanted to add a more obvious answer in case it helps someone out there!)