# Thinkster Mean Stack tutorial - Register action gives 500 error - Using Chrome and Windows 7

Tags: http

I worked through the Flapper News tutorial and everything was working until I got the the register/login functionality. Am getting a 500 API error when submitting the Register form. The URL http://localhost:3000/#/register displays the form fine and allows entry. The express server screen shows:
POST /register 500 640.874 ms - 1901

Running on Windows 7 machine

Other non-authenticated URLs are working fine, for example:
    http://localhost:3000/#/home
    http://localhost:3000/#/posts/5ccc7f0f114e382a80d3b7ef

The Chrome console shows:
    angular.js:11881 POST http://localhost:3000/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:11881
    n @ angular.js:11642
    g @ angular.js:11352
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:16170
    $eval @ angular.js:17444
    $digest @ angular.js:17257
    $apply @ angular.js:17552
    (anonymous) @ angular.js:25627
    Sf @ angular.js:3488
    d @ angular.js:3476

**angular.js:11881 code**:
    xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post);

error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

### app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/news');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
require('./models/Users');

require('./config/passport');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

---

### routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var passport = require('passport');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var auth = jwt({secret: 'SECRET', userProperty: 'payload'});

router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(posts);
  });
});

router.post('/posts', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post(req.body);
  post.author = req.payload.username;

  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});


// Preload post objects on routes with ':post'
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error("can't find post")); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});

// Preload comment objects on routes with ':comment'
router.param('comment', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Comment.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, comment){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!comment) { return next(new Error("can't find comment")); }

    req.comment = comment;
    return next();
  });
});


// return a post
router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    res.json(post);
  });
});


// upvote a post
router.put('/posts/:post/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.upvote(function(err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});


// create a new comment
router.post('/posts/:post/comments', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var comment = new Comment(req.body);
  comment.post = req.post;
  comment.author = req.payload.username;

  comment.save(function(err, comment){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    req.post.comments.push(comment);
    req.post.save(function(err, post) {
      if(err){ return next(err); }

      res.json(comment);
    });
  });
});


// upvote a comment
router.put('/posts/:post/comments/:comment/upvote', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  req.comment.upvote(function(err, comment){
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(comment);
  });
});


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    if(user){
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password){
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'Please fill out all fields'});
  }

  var user = new User();

  user.username = req.body.username;

  user.setPassword(req.body.password)

  user.save(function (err){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()})
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

### public/javascript/angularApp.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
        postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
          return posts.getAll();
        }]
      }
    })
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts/{id}',
      templateUrl: '/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
          return posts.get($stateParams.id);
        }]
      }
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: '/login.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home');
        }
      }]
    })
    .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: '/register.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      onEnter: ['$state', 'auth', function($state, auth){
        if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
          $state.go('home');
        }
      }]
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };

  o.get = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res){
      return res.data;
    });
  };

  o.getAll = function() {
    return $http.get('/posts').success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.posts);
    });
  };

  o.create = function(post) {
    return $http.post('/posts', post, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      o.posts.push(data);
    });
  };

  o.upvote = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      post.upvotes += 1;
    });
  };

  o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
    return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments', comment, {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    });
  };

  o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/'+ comment._id + '/upvote', {
      headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
      comment.upvotes += 1;
    });
  };

  return o;
}])
.factory('auth', ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', function($http, $window, $rootScope){
   var auth = {
    saveToken: function (token){
      $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'] = token;
    },
    getToken: function (){
      return $window.localStorage['flapper-news-token'];
    },
    isLoggedIn: function(){
      var token = auth.getToken();

      if(token){
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

        return payload.exp > Date.now() / 1000;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    currentUser: function(){
      if(auth.isLoggedIn()){
        var token = auth.getToken();
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));

        return payload.username;
      }
    },
    register: function(user){
      return $http.post('/register', user).success(function(data){
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
      });
    },
    logIn: function(user){
      return $http.post('/login', user).success(function(data){
        auth.saveToken(data.token);
      });
    },
    logOut: function(){
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('flapper-news-token');
    }
  };

  return auth;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
'auth',
function($scope, posts, auth){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

  $scope.addPost = function(){
    if($scope.title === '') { return; }
    posts.create({
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link,
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.link = '';
  };

  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    posts.upvote(post);
  };

}])
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
'post',
'auth',
function($scope, posts, post, auth){
  $scope.post = post;
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;

  $scope.addComment = function(){
    if($scope.body === '') { return; }
    posts.addComment(post._id, {
      body: $scope.body,
      author: 'user',
    }).success(function(comment) {
      $scope.post.comments.push(comment);
    });
    $scope.body = '';
  };

  $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(comment){
    posts.upvoteComment(post, comment);
  };
}])
.controller('AuthCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$state',
'auth',
function($scope, $state, auth){
  $scope.user = {};

  $scope.register = function(){
    auth.register($scope.user).error(function(error){
      $scope.error = error;
    }).then(function(){
      $state.go('home');
    });
  };

  $scope.logIn = function(){
    auth.logIn($scope.user).error(function(error){
      $scope.error = error;
    }).then(function(){
      $state.go('home');
    });
  };
}])
.controller('NavCtrl', [
'$scope',
'auth',
function($scope, auth){
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
  $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  $scope.logOut = auth.logOut;
}]);
```

Comment: Can you attach the frontend code that send the POST request, and the server code that deal with `POST /register`?

Answer (score 0):

Found another posting on stack overflow that described and solved my issue

[TypeError: The "digest" argument is required and must not be undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44606054/typeerror-the-digest-argument-is-required-and-must-not-be-undefined)

The specific error I was having was:

## The "digest" argument must be one of type string or null. Received type undefined

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "digest" argument must be one of type string or null. Received type undefined
    at check (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:56:13)
    at Object.pbkdf2Sync (internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js:45:5)
    at model.UserSchema.methods.setPassword (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\models\Users.js:21:22)
    at P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\routes\index.js:140:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)
    at router (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at P:\data\thinkster\flappernews\flapper-news\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
```